# Passing multiple parameter via GET with params keyword to an MVC controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, actionmethod

Is there any way to pass multiple paramters by using params keyword to an action method with GET as below?

```
http://.../Method/param1/param2/param3/..../paramN
```

Action method should be as below:

```
public ActionResult Method(params string[] parameters)
{
//Do what ever.
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it that way? I guess you could implement your own model binder as long as the url routing allows for your mapping.

Comment: Do need this for Url routing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this for url routing you can use something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Name", "param/{*params}", new { controller = ..., action = ... });

ActionResult MyAction(string params) {
    foreach(string param in params.Split("/")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to sent int values to   Action(params int[] arr)  and then work with int array on server not with strings?